# Dividing a const by a generic in Rust

Tags: generics, constants, rust

I have a struct `Vec3<T>`, how can I implement the following method ?

```
impl<T: num::Num + num::Float> Not<Vec3<T>> for Vec3<T> {
    fn not(&self) -> Vec3<T> {
        *self * (1.0 / (*self % *self).sqrt())
    }
}
```

**error: mismatched types: expected `_`, found `T` (expected floating-point variable, found type parameter)**

Type of `1.0` is `_` while type of `(*self % *self).sqrt()` is `T`. And it seems it can't divide a _ by a T.

I tried various casting for 1.0 :

```
*self * ((1.0 as T) / (*self % *self).sqrt())
```

**error: non-scalar cast: `_` as `T`**

```
*self * (1.0.div((*self % *self).sqrt()))
```

**error: mismatched types: expected `&_`, found `T` (expected &-ptr, found type parameter)**

What is the sleekest way to implement this method ?

**Edit 1:**
As requested, here is my full code :

```
use std::num::Float;

pub struct Vec3<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
    pub z: T,
}

impl<T> Vec3<T> {
    pub fn new(x: T, y: T, z: T) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 { x: x, y: y, z: z }
    }
}

impl<T: Float> Add<T, Vec3<T>> for Vec3<T> {
    fn add(&self, rhs: &T) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 { x: self.x + *rhs, y: self.y + *rhs, z: self.z + *rhs }
    }
}

impl<T: Float> Add<Vec3<T>, Vec3<T>> for Vec3<T> {
    fn add(&self, rhs: &Vec3<T>) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 { x: self.x + rhs.x, y: self.y + rhs.y, z: self.z + rhs.z }
    }
}

impl<T: Float> Mul<T, Vec3<T>> for Vec3<T> {
    fn mul(&self, rhs: &T) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 { x: self.x * *rhs, y: self.y * *rhs, z: self.z * *rhs }
    }
}

// x % y : dot-product
impl<T: Float> Rem<Vec3<T>, T> for Vec3<T> {
    fn rem(&self, rhs: &Vec3<T>) -> T {
        self.x + rhs.x * self.y + rhs.y * self.z + rhs.z
    }
}

// x ^ y : cross-product
impl<T: Float> BitXor<Vec3<T>, Vec3<T>> for Vec3<T> {
    fn bitxor(&self, rhs: &Vec3<T>) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 { x: self.y * rhs.z - self.z * rhs.y,
               y: self.z * rhs.x - self.x * rhs.z,
               z: self.x * rhs.y - self.y * rhs.x }
    }
}

// !x : Norm
impl Not<Vec3<f32>> for Vec3<f32> {
    fn not(&self) -> Vec3<f32> {
        *self * (1.0f32 / (*self % *self).sqrt())
    }
}

impl Not<Vec3<f64>> for Vec3<f64> {
    fn not(&self) -> Vec3<f64> {
        *self * (1.0f64 / (*self % *self).sqrt())
    }
}
```

I would have used `Num` instead of `Float` to be able to have integer vectors, but since it's deprecated, I think the better option is to use macro to duplicate code for all types. Here I duplicated `Not` for `f32` and `f64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literals can only be of primitive types. You can't cast a literal to some generic type.

For constants like `1.0` you can use methods like [`Float::one()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/trait.Float.html#tymethod.one), so your specific example could be rewritten as

```
impl<T: num::Float> Not<Vec3<T>> for Vec3<T> {
    fn not(&self) -> Vec3<T> {
        *self * (num::Float::one() / (*self % *self).sqrt())
    }
}
```

(note that I removed `Num` bound because it is deprecated and in this case it is entirely superseded by `Float`)

To convert arbitrary values to instances of some specific `Float` type you can use [`NumCast::from()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/trait.NumCast.html#tymethod.from) method:

```
let x: T = num::NumCast::from(3.14f64);
```

BTW, you may find [this accepted RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/369) interesting.

**Update**

It is likely that you won't be able to implement `Float` for your structure because it has a lot of methods specific to bare floats, like mantissa size. I guess you will have to add methods like `one()` and `zero()` and probably casts from numbers yourself. Then you will be able to write

```
impl<T: num::Float> Not<Vec3<T>> for Vec3<T> {
    fn not(&self) -> Vec3<T> {
        *self * (Vec3::one() / (*self % *self).sqrt())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have this error now : the type of this value must be known in this context

Comment: As I understand it, for now, generics are very limited, and it's not going to be better by deleting std::num::Num

Comment: @AurélienFusil-Delahaye, could you please give the full code? I need instances of operations for `Vec3<T>`, otherwise I can't compile this particular snippet.

Comment: This probably happens because `Vec3<T>` doesn't implement `Float`. However, given the current situation you probably won't be able to use `One` separately from `Float`, and you also probably won't be able to implement `Float` for `Vec3<T>`... I guess you will have to implement your own method to create `Vec3<T>` basic constants.