# Avoid casting floating point constant

Tags: casting, rust

I'm creating cargo that (among other things) will implement idiomatic angle measurment. When creating methods to convert between angle units I've found problem:

```
impl<T> Angle<T>
where T: Float {
    pub fn to_deg(self) -> Self {
        Deg(match self {
            Rad(v) =>  v * cast(180.0 / f64::consts::PI).unwrap(),
            Deg(v) =>  v,
            Grad(v) => v * cast(180.0 / 200.0).unwrap() // how to get rid of this cast?
        })
    }
}
```

[Runnable](http://is.gd/AIg28a)

The cast of `180.0 / 200.0` seem really unneded for me? Is there any way to get rid of this?

When I delete cast then I get:

```
src/angles.rs:42:28: 42:33 error: mismatched types:
 expected `T`,
    found `_`
(expected type parameter,
    found floating-point variable) [E0308]
src/angles.rs:42             Grad(v) => v * 180.0 / 200.0
                                            ^~~~~
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally one that runs on the [Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/). This lets us help you with very little friction, making it more likely that you will get a timely and good response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dividing a const by a generic in Rust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441224/dividing-a-const-by-a-generic-in-rust)

Comment: Here's [an example of a **M**CVE](http://is.gd/g4ZXKh)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a generic function with a type parameter, such as `T`, *you don't get to choose the type*. The type is forced on you by the caller of the function.

The error here is that you're trying to assign a specific `f32`/`f64` type to a type `T`, which could be *anything* that implements `Float`.

You know in practice it's going to be either one of the floating-point types, but theoretically the type system won't stop someone from implementing `Float` on a string or an array, or a tuple of two function pointers, or any other bizarre thing that can't be assigned a float. When the compiler can't guarantee it'll always work, including in theory in the future, then it won't accept it.

If you want to assign a float value to `T`, you have to declare that this operation is possible, e.g. by adding `f32: Into<T>`, and using `180f32.into()`.